# iOS JMImageCache: Use Default Image

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I just started using JMImageCache which is really nice and easy to use.  There is just one issue, it doesn't support using a default image until the remote image loads.

**Does anyone know how this can be done?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `imageForURL:delegate:` returns `nil`, simply set your default image, which you can replace when the delegate method `cache:didDownloadImage:forURL:` is called.

Comment: Well that was easy enough. :)  Thank you!